# Downloading dropbox read-only files

Tags: javascript, pdf, download, dropbox

I have access to a dropbox link, where I am able to look at some pdf files but not to download them. It is interesting that many tools are available online in order to solve this issue on google drive, but it seems like no one ever thaught about dropbox. The only way I personally found is to download every single png file from the "network" tab. Surely I could automate this process, but the files still remain png's, not allowing me to select any of the text, and reducing the file quality.
I have tried using some js code I found for google drive, but none of them are working in this case. I would be extremely thankful if someone could help me with an idea.
I would like to make an example, but I am not able to create suche a file by myself because I do not own a subscription.
I'm uploading here a sample which also is not available for download:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/19hk751qwexc5pi/usRAP_brochure.pdf?dl=0
Note that with this file it is not possible to select the text, while in mine this is possible. This brings me to think that there must be a way to download the file as a pdf.
Thank you very much

Comment: I just updated the question. The weird thing is that I am able to highlight the text, so I guess there must be at least a way to "scrape" this information. Thank you very much for your answer though @KJ

Comment: I mean, if the page is able to render those images and make their text highlitable, then there must be a way to download the same. I am going to update the page in order to let you better understand what I mean

Comment: This site is awesome! Do you know any free alternative similar to this one, which lets me view the file and download the images as a pdf? Not publishing them would be better though. Also, I just found out about Acrobat's text-scan option!

Comment: Well, you solved my issue! Thank you a lot!